# How can I calculate values using multiple mgrid with different origins and or shapes

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to see if I can work with GIS raster arithmetic in python using numpy ndarrays. I am calculating probability values (z) for multiple defined areas (x, y), and want to subsequently add up the probabilities. The grids overlap but don't have the same dimensions in x, y. The result should show the probabilities added where the grids overlap and keep the probability values of the respective grids where they don't.

I have worked out the grids, but cannot add them together. Can this be done in numpy or do I need to use rasterio/GDAL tools? Are mgrids the best approach?

I've created some simple mgrids to illustrate the issue.

```
ys, xs = np.mgrid[5:15:5j, 0:5:5j]
f = lambda x, y: x * y + 1
vf = np.vectorize(f)
r = vf(xs, ys)
c1 = np.array([xs, ys, r])

ys2, xs2 = np.mgrid[4:9:6j, 1:6:6j]
f2 = lambda x, y: x + y * 2
vf2 = np.vectorize(f2)
r2 = vf2(xs2, ys2)
c2 = np.array([xs2, ys2, r2])
```

To plot them:

```
plt.contourf(c1[0], c1[1], c1[2], levels = 100)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[c1 plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8VcM.png)

```
plt.contourf(c2[0], c2[1], c2[2], levels = 100)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[c2 plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKCNB.png)

Comment: Side note: you don't need `vectorize` if you're only using elementwise arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1):

Your two grids aren't in a strict superset-subset relationship. Here's how they look like:

[image: two grids plotted in 2d]

As you can see, while the *domains* of the two grids overlap, the actual grid points are disjoint save a single grid point.

How would you accumulate these data points? The arrays you have store a probability `z_i = z(x_i, y_i)` for each grid point. The function is discrete and only defined on a grid. You cannot add two datasets unless their grid points correspond to one another. It doesn't make any sense to do so.

What you *could* do is interpolate the data from either of the grids and add *that* to the other grid (or a third common grid). This will not be exact, and can only work if your data is smooth enough. Furthermore, your grids only have partial overlap, so you will have to figure out how to handle regions where you have multiple points versus those where you don't. `contourf` will also accept data that is 2d plaid (i.e. as if generated from `mgrid`). So the answer your original question is "you can't straightforwardly do that".